# Juniper router how to check the BGP process port?

Tags: router, bgp, juniper

Juniper router how to check the BGP process port?

If I have a router with IP address `12.12.21.1`, we know it run a BGP process, which use TCP 179 port as default.

How can I check if port 179 is opened for BGP?

We know that we can use `netstat -tlnp | grep 179`, like on Linux servers, to find its process, but how to do it on a Juniper Router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Junos, use `show system connections | match 179`